# subtracting two lines of code

Tags: python-3.x

I need to subtract Line 5 from Line 4 and Enter 0 if negative and this keeps coming up

```
def main():
    print("IRS Form 1040EZ Tax Computation Program (2015)")
    print()
    sal = eval(input("Line 1:  Enter wages, salaries, and tips: "))
    tint = eval(input("Line 2:  Enter taxable interest: "))
    print()
    agros = print("Line 4: Adjusted Gross Income: ",sal + tint)
    print()
    exempt = eval(input("Line 5:  Exemption Amount $ "))
    print("Line 6:  Taxable Income: $",agros - exempt)

main()

IRS Form 1040EZ Tax Computation Program (2015)

Line 1:  Enter wages, salaries, and tips: 27500.00
Line 2:  Enter taxable interest: 250.00

Line 4: Adjusted Gross Income:  27750.0

Line 5:  Exemption Amount $ 10150

Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 22, in main
    print("Line 6:  Taxable Income: $",agros - exempt)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
agros = print("Line 4: Adjusted Gross Income: ",sal + tint)
```

You are assigning `agros` the result of calling `print`:

```
>>> a = print("")
>>> print(a)
None
```

You need to do the assignment and printing separately:

```
agros = sal + tint
print("Line 4: Adjusted Gross Income: ", agros)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a python guy, but I would try:

```
agros = sal + tint
print("Line 4: Adjusted Gross Income: ", agros)
```